# How to detect delay of Pubsub to Bigquery subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

How can one compute delay between pub sub publish time and arrival to bigquery when using pub/sub to bigquery subscription (not through dataflow)?

I have `publish_time` from pub sub metadata.
And a field in BQ in the table where data flows that auto populates with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

I was hoping to just check the timestamp difference but noticed that quite often current_timestamp is earlier than publish_time.

It's about 350 messages/s and BQ table is partitioned by `_PARTITIONTIME` / hour if this makes any difference.
Im also wondering what is expected delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Google Support that [this is expected behaviour](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249782549).

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps having time zone issues? Even though some minor skew across clocks is possible, it is very unlikely that the skew will be greater than the latency of processing.

Answer (score -1):

As I understnad - not in the GA at this moment, but do you think you can use BigQuery [default cloumn values](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values)? And use a `current_timesstamp` as a [default expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#default_value_expression)?

I mean inside a `create table if not exists` clause, defining columns, use something like:

```
    -- pubsub streaming subscription metadata
    subscription_name        string    not null options(description="A name of a source pubsub subscription.")
    , message_id             string    not null options(description="A unique identifier of the pubsub message.")
    , publish_time           timestamp not null options(description="A timestamp when the pubsub message was published.")
    , bq_record_ingest_time  timestamp default current_timestamp() options(description="A timestamp when the record was ingested into the BQ table.")
  -- and so on, other columns
```

and by using the differnce between the `record_ingest_time` and the `publish_time` values you mihgt get the latency, I guess.

Comment: that's exactly what i do now, please refer to original question for more details. the issue is that im getting current_timestamp is earlier than publish_time that doesnt make sense.